# Getting multiple files over FTP with ftp_get and ftp_nlist

Tags: php, ftp

I'm attempting to get multiple files from another domain using ftp_get and ftp_nlist. ftp_nlist expects a resource and a string, but the below returns

> ftp_nlist() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

and

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    <?php
// Connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "hostname";
$ftp_username ="username";
$ftp_userpass = "password";
$includes = "/directory/";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

// Get file list
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $includes);

// Loop through for file 1
foreach ($contents as $file) {
   $local_file = '/path/to/file.php';
   $server_file = '/path/to/file.php';
   ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
}

// Loop through for file 2
foreach ($contents as $file) {
   $local_file = '/path/to/file.php';
   $server_file = '/path/to/file.php';
   ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable `$conn_id` that you pass to `ftp_nlist()` is not defined. You need to pass `$ftp_conn` in **all** `ftp_*` functions instead. (`ftp_get()` in your case)

Check `ftp_close()` as well, to be sure you did not forget to close connection.

I'd recommend to use a wrapper for `ftp_` functions, like https://github.com/dg/ftp-php, to make debugging easier. You will be able to use `Exceptions` and catch them like this:

```
try {
    $ftp = new Ftp;
    $ftp->connect($ftp_server);
    $ftp->login($ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
    $ftp->nlist($includes);

} catch (FtpException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Fair point, thank you. Even with $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); defined, the foreach loops are still seen as invalid. Any thoughts?

Comment: A common solution while dealing with `ftp` is to use **passive mode**. Try adding `ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);` right after connection

Comment: If it still returns `false`, look what `error_get_last()` show you.

Comment: It looks like the issue is ftp_nlist is not returning an array

Comment: `ftp_nlist` returns **false** on error.  What error do you have?

Comment: If I test the array it returns not an array - my guess is that it isn't understanding the input for directory. I can successfully get a single file, just not multiple files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142540/discussion-between-wormi4ok-and-toomanyairmiles).